# How to change this formula dynamic

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I want to change this:

```
='D:\Documents\Financial\[m1.xlsm]main'!B$4
```

To something like this:

```
="'D:\Documents\Financial\[m" & A1 & ".xlsm]main'!B$4"
```

that A1 has value of 1 and A2 value of 2 and ....

Is it possible?

Comment: It is possible with the use of VBA. Here is similar question and answer https://superuser.com/questions/1825551/add-link-reference-in-excel-using-onedrive

Answer (score 1):

### A Worksheet Change: Retrieve Cell Value From Different Files

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const RETURN_FORMULA As String _
        = "='D:\Documents\Financial\[m<PLACE_HOLDER>.xlsm]main'!B$4"
    Const FIRST_CELL As String = "A1"
    Const RETURN_COLUMN As String = "B"
    Const IF_INVALID As Variant = Empty
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Target.Worksheet
    
    Dim trg As Range:
    With ws.Range(FIRST_CELL)
        Set trg = .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(trg, Target)
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim icell As Range, ErrNumber As Long
    
    For Each icell In irg.Cells
        With ws.Cells(icell.Row, RETURN_COLUMN)
            On Error Resume Next
                .Value = Replace( _
                    RETURN_FORMULA, "<PLACE_HOLDER>", CStr(icell.Value))
                ErrNumber = Err.Number
            On Error GoTo 0
            If ErrNumber <> 0 Then .Value = IF_INVALID
        End With
    Next icell
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you VBasic2008 but i think this part of code is better... anyway thank you for your time:

```
Dim THE_PATH_1 As String
THE_PATH_1 = "D:\Documents\Financial\m"
Dim THE_CY As Long
THE_CY = 0
Do
    THE_CY = THE_CY + 1
    If Len(Dir(THE_PATH_1 & CStr(THE_CY) & ".xlsm")) <> 0 Then
        Range("A" & CStr(THE_CY + 1)).Formula = "='D:\Documents\Financial\[m" & CStr(THE_CY) & ".xlsm]main'!D$1"
        Range("B" & CStr(THE_CY + 1)).Formula = "='D:\Documents\Financial\[m" & CStr(THE_CY) & ".xlsm]main'!B$2"
    Else
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```